# Movie about androids with a western theme

Tags: story-identification

I know its not Westworld and tired of getting that on google.  its set when all humans are long dead or at least very rare.  the main character is like a hired gunfighter who arrives in a town of other androids that just had a fight and a headless android gets the gunfighter to attach his head to another headless droid.  the story revolves around a gang terrorizing the town and the gunfighter was hired to stop them.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Specifically things like when you saw it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By any chance is it [Omega Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_Doom)?

[image: Movie poster, taken from wikipedia page]

It's the only dystopian future robot cowboy movie I can remember.

There's definetly a character that is simply a robot head, and a city/town of andriods/robot people.

Comment: thats it.  I been looking through bookmarks for days trying to find that movie.

Comment: @MattLeuisVergil: Good stuff, I'm happy to help. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if you believe this is it. Thanks :)